# How to find out if an array is empty?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

I have a boolean flag and I have to func (fun animation and fun reAninimation - it is transition between two drawables).
This is the transition between the two drawings

Idea of this class is I have two side of coins. I added it in an array. If array is empty, I only call animation, if it not empty I firstly call reAnimation and then animation.

My array:

```
 var arrayShape: Array<Drawable>? = null
```

it is a part of the OnCreate method.

```
override OnCreate() ...
if(isArrayEmpty(arrayShape!!)) shapeReAnimation()
      randomShape()
```

it is flag method

```
fun isArrayEmpty(array : Array<Drawable>):Boolean {
    return array.size > 1 && array[0] !=null
  }
```

and some future fun reAnimation() which now should show some Toast.

```
fun shapeReAnimation() {
   // if (arrayShape!![0] == resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.back_circle))
      ToastUtils.showErorMessage(context, "first")
  }
```

when I run my project and click for fShape, It show me NPE (    kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException)
and project have stopded

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever set `arrayShape` to anything but null. Don't use `!!` on something unless you're 100% sure it's not null. In addition, `array[0] != null` will always be true because `Drawable` isn't a nullable type (unless it's a tricky alias to a nullable type).

Answer (score 2):

You can use like that... because null is not possible and not advisable for the list or any collection(without array), So can achieve your solution with a help of ArrayList

```
 val arrayShape = ArrayList<Drawable>()

    if (arrayShape.isEmpty())
        Toast.makeText(this, "Array is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Array is not Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use safe call on the array since it is nullable. Also provide a default value when it is null.

```
if(arrayShape?.isEmpty() ?: true)
```